# How to find mulitiple column by using join instead of group by?

Tags: sql, join, subquery

**This is used for subquery . But i need this by using join**

```
select first_name,department_id,salary from employees
where (department_id , salary) in (select department_id ,max (salary) as max_sal from employees
group by department_id);
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you can't have it without a subquery.  You can use a join in place of the `IN` operator, though:

```
SELECT
  e.first_name AS first_name,
  e.department_id AS department_id,
  e.salary AS salary
FROM
 employees e
 JOIN (
   SELECT department_id, MAX(salary) AS salary
   FROM employees
   GROUP BY department_id
 ) e_max
   ON e.department_id = e_max.department_id AND e.salary = e_max.salary
```

Comment: @ypercube, I *did* use a derived table, if you want to be picky about terminology.  I could also have factored it out as a common table expression, which may be what you were thinking of.  I don't see much value in distinguishing the query defining a derived table or a CTE from a "subquery", so I typically don't.  My apologies if that caused any confusion.

Comment: Yes, you did use a derived table, indeed. I guess my point was that it can be done without a join (using window functions). Sorry, did not express myself clear.